# Добавление картинки в листвью

Tags: android, изображения

```
    // Находим наш list 
    ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandable_list_view);

    //Создаем набор данных для адаптера        
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> groups = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> children1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> children2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> children3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    children1.add("");
    children1.add("");
    children1.add("");
    children1.add("");
    groups.add(children1);
    groups.add(children2);
    children2.add(" ");
    children2.add(" ");
    groups.add(children3);
    children3.add(" ");
    children3.add(" ");
    children3.add(" ");

   //Создаем адаптер и передаем context и список с данными
    ExpListAdapter adapter = new ExpListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), groups);;
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

хотелось бы узнать, как можно ли добавлять картинки рядом с индексом арейлиста? и как это реализовать? извиняюсь если не понятно изъясняюсь..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно свой адаптер читаем например тут: [Кастомный ExpandableListView в Android](http://habrahabr.ru/post/147546/)

Comment: в твоем апаптере есть вьюха, на нее надо добавить имейджВью, в который ты будешь добавлять рисунок, а дальше, если рисунок простой, например, просто значек - можно это делать в адаптере, а если сложнее - например ава контакта, передавать объектами в адаптер

Comment: спасибо) а не могли бы вы подсказать как извлеч индексы из эрейлиста, я вот думаю может по индексу просто рисовать картинку?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)